# XCode Project: how to build sub-projects as static libraries?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I need to build sub-projects as static libraries, not too sure how I should do it, should I:

1. Compile all sub-projects one by one (or compile the main project once?)
2. Find .a files for sub-projects in products folder, copy them to main project
3. copy all .h files for sub-projects into a folder in main projects
4. remove all sub-projects

are the above steps correct?

Also, do I need to compile them in release(or debug) mode, and for simulator and device respectively?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use static library in my project. The steps you mentioned are correct except remove all sub projects? Why do you need to have sub projects at all. They all ideally should be independent libraries compiled independently and you just add .a file and main header files in the main project. If you do this you don't need to update your main project when your static library changes. You just need to update .a file or .h incase they changed....and yes you will need to compile static libraries in release mode when you want to submit your App to appstore. Simulator and device really doesn't matter as it's not going to run. It's all matter is iOS target and base SDK that you complied against.

Comment: Subprojects allow you to tweak the library and have it recompile automatically.  These are static libraries, so you will have to recompile the entire project to update them anyway (they will end up inside the final binary, not separate like dynamic libraries).

Comment: May be it's useful when you have many libraries? I have only one static library and I maintain it like the way I mentioned and find it easy. Is there anything wrong with my approach? I went through the link you posted. There's something new that I don't know. I will definitely follow that approach if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong, it just adds a few extra steps if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Yes you may be right but I didn't know any other approach of attaching libraries as subprojects like three20 does. I researched a lot but couldn't get it and came out with my own solution as posted. I think the link you posted will create same project hierarchy as three20 library and its sub projects. Am I correct?

Comment: I believe so, from some looking it looks like they've organized their project into separate projects (or perhaps separate targets).

Comment: Thanks but where do I find all the header .h files for sub-projects?

Comment: That must be created by you. Aren't they? Where do you stuck? Please give details.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need to do any of that because Xcode will do it all for you...

Basically, just drag the library project in, set the dependencies and be done:  See [this page](http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/easy-xcode-static-library-subprojects-and-submodules) for details.